# Python Coding Questions

Tags: python

I am attempting to modify some code, that will mask private information.

The code worked as represented below.

```
def checkPiData(fieldValue):
    retVal = ""
    if len(fieldValue) > 0 :
        retVal = "Available"
    else:
        retVal = "Unavailable"

    return retVal
```

The issue I run into , is that some of these fields, I need to mask return a text value of "NULL"  so I print Available, for that value, because of the `len` being sent to anything larger then zero.  This isn't accurate, and causes me issues.

I've tried to modify the code to

```
def checkPiData(fieldValue):
    retVal = ""
    if str(fieldValue) == "NULL":
        retVal = "Unavailable"
    elif len(fieldValue) > 0 :
        retVal = "Available"
    else:
        retVal = "Unavailable"

    return retVal
```

I can't get the code to see NULL,  it keeps reverting back to `len > 0`

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What type of data is `fieldValue`? If it is already a string, you don't need to cast it to a string

Comment: `checkPiData('NULL')` will return `"Unavailable"`, so I don't understand the problem

Comment: @cricket_007  the issue, is (what I believe) is that in a Date of Birth field,  which is a datetime field in SQL,  there is a text value of "NULL"  I cant figure out how to account for that text value.  my code, thinks the text value of "NULL" is longer then 0 so, it print available.

Comment: @PatrickLausen: Please add print "%s" % type(fieldValue) and print "fieldValue = %s" % fieldValue to the start of your function and tell us what it prints out.

Comment: @DavidCullen thank you for the help here, and patience, I am learning how to code via trial and error.     I've tried to input that print line, but I get a syntax error on the last quote.

Comment: @PatrickLausen: Are you using Python 3? If so, you'll have to put parenthesis around your print arguments. I just checked, and Python 3 will complain about the last quote if you don't have the parenthesis. So you need to add print("%s" % type(fieldValue)) and print("fieldValue = %s" % fieldValue) to the beginning of the function.

Comment: @DavidCullen thank you very much.      I am getting back <class 'str'> from the print statement.   is that what you looking for?  I attempted to change it to the following,  but I am still having a heck of a time                                def checkPiData(fieldValue):
    
    print("%s" % type(fieldValue)) and print("fieldValue = %s" % fieldValue)
    if "NULL" in str(fieldValue) or  len(fieldValue) <1:
      return  "Unavailable"

        
    else:
        return  "available"

Comment: additionally,  I've tried to pre-format  the data in my sql query   CONVERT(char(10), DEBTOR.BIRTH_DATE, 126) AS 'BIRTH_DATE'   I don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: @PatrickLausen: I need the output of print("fieldValue = %s" % fieldValue)

Answer (score 0):

whats the input value you are casting to string? are you sure you don't want to compare against None? in that case you can just do:

```
if filedValue:
  ...
```

Or

```
if filedValue is not None:
...
```

If you want to be 100% safe.
If not the case please post the input argument that makes your function fail

Comment: Use `is not` when comparing with `None`.

Comment: The input values,  for the column I am struggling with, is represented at datetime in sql,  I think what Im struggling with ,  is that the value is either  a date value or a text value of "NULL"

Comment: @pzp thanks I was not aware of the distinction for the None case, but it makes sense since None is not an actual value. I fixed it in the code

Comment: @PatrickLausen unluckily I am not expert in sql, if you can post what the dateTime object gets converted to in string will make easier to figure out why the thing is failing. Might it be for a space? try to flip the condition like this:
If NULL in filedValue: return "unavailable"

Comment: @MarcoGiordano I tried the below,  I received the same result, but not errors,  I think I am struggling with casting the field correctly?   def checkPiData(fieldValue):
    retVal = ""
    if  "NULL" in str(fieldValue):
        retVal = "Unavailable"
    if  "NULL" not in str(fieldValue) and len(fieldValue) > 0:
        retVal = "Available"
    
    else:
        retVal = "Unavailable"

    return retVal

Comment: We need to see more data, if you want us to help you.
please provide us with the value: str(fieldValue) and also with his type before string cast : type(filedValue).
Otherwise we can only make wild guesses

Comment: @MarcoGiordano I appreciate the help and the patience.   I may not fully understand what you are requesting.   I am feeding the data in,  via this query that is in my py file,  if I am missing the boat I apologize .    i also haven't figured out how to copy and paste code in this comment fox and get the format correct.            
    name = checkPiData(row['Expr1'])
    address = checkPiData(row['STREET'])
    ssn = checkPiData(row['SSN'])
    dob = checkPiData(str(row['BIRTH_DATE']))
    home_phone = checkPiData(row['PHONE'])
    biz_phone = checkPiData(row['MOBIL_PHONE'])

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that something returns the string 'NULL' or just no value (in this case your code should've worked fine)? If you mean by string you could simply use something like this?:

```
def checkPiData(fieldValue):
    retVal = ""
    if len(fieldValue) > 0 and fieldValue != None:
        retVal = "Available"
    else:
        retVal = "Unavailable"

    return retVal

# This is to check the code
print checkPiData('')
print checkPiData('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the help,  after a lot of reading and messing around with things

turns out the following code works,

```
if "None" in str(fieldValue) or  len(fieldValue) <1:
  return  "Unavailable"


else:
    return  "available"
```

what I learned today, is use print to diagnose the problems.

thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to your own question can be improved:

```
def checkPiData(fieldValue):
    if fieldValue is None or not len(fieldValue):
        return "Unavailable"
    return "Available"
```